# how to dlopen so file in apache module development with apxs

Tags: c++, c, dlopen, apache-modules, apxs2

I'm trying open a so file in apache module with this code :

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <httpd.h>
#include <http_protocol.h>
#include <http_config.h>



static int helloworld_handler(request_rec* r)
{
if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "helloworld"))
    return DECLINED;

if (r->method_number != M_GET)
    return HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;


// here i try to load so file --------------------------------
typedef bool (*hello_t)();
void *handle;

handle = dlopen ("/lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
hello_t echo = (hello_t) dlsym(handle, "echo");

echo();


 // ------------------------------------------------------------
 return OK;
}

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t* pool)
{
    ap_hook_handler(helloworld_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
}


module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA helloworld_module = {
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    register_hooks
   };
```

i'm included dlfcn.h header file but not work!
compiling with this : apxs -i -a -c mod_helloworld.c
i'm trying compile with -ldl : apxs -i -a -c Wc,-ldl mod_helloworld.c but don't working. i have this error in dlerror() : 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_helloworld.so: undefined symbol: echo

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a good description to start with. Have you checked and identified errors after `dlopen` and `dlsym`? Take a look at the examples in the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)

Comment: Extensive logging is usually a key to success in a new/unknown environment.

Comment: i can't to check error after dlopen and dlsym in apache module, i'm using apxs for compile this module, i cant use gcc to compile and i can't linked -ldl see this : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apxs.html

Comment: What prevents you from checking dl* functions result codes and logging them using [apache logging API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/group__APACHE__CORE__LOG.html) ?

Comment: i have this error in dlerror () : /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_helloworld.so: undefined symbol: echo

Comment: Guess it explains everything. Try this command:  `nm -D /var/www/html/mylib.so | grep echo`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond the result is : "00000000000007a0 T echo", my .so file has not problem, i'm using this file on other c++ application but this not work in apache module. i think the problem from compiling with apxs

Comment: You seem to have replaced your code with something completely different, but I cannot see any dlerror in it...

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I'm adedd dlerror in my code now and result this massage :  /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_helloworld.so: undefined symbol: echo.. I'm put all module code in post now

Comment: You seem to have replaced your code with something completely different, but I cannot see any dlerror in it...